# The correct way to implement a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Sorry for the vauge title, I couldn't think of a better one.  I am creating a sports tipping application.  I have a games model that consists of teamA and teamB.  I also have a 'tip' model that will consist of the game id and the team id that the user selects.  A tip only relates to one team. (one to many).

What I want is a form that will list all open games with the 2 teams being check boxes that the user can select.
For example :

GAME 1

. teamA   . teamB

GAME 2

.teamC    . teamD

......
etc.

I want to know what is the correct 'rails' way of doing something like this ?  I want to know the 'right' way of approaching something (for a change).  What I am doing now seems to be on the way to working but it feels like there may be a better way.

My idea was to have the new method in my tips_controller pass the games to the form and then let the create method do the work of creating several 'tips'.  I am looking at the nested_form gem but am not exactly sure that this will fit https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form .

Thankyou for any ideas, I am new to ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767171/rails-jquery-updating-a-div-underneath-a-facebox-div) I think you could do with spending some time on railscasts (or similar) learning the basics.

In particular Ryan's done some great tutorials about nested forms:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

And also a few about has many relationships

Good luck